# How to add regression functions in python, or create a new regression function from given coefficients?

Tags: python, function, scikit-learn, regression, statsmodels

I have one regression function, `g1(x) = 5x - 1` for one data point.
I have another regression function, `g2(x) =  3x + 4`.

I want to add these two models to create a final regression model, `G(x)`.

That means:

```
G(x) = g1(x) + g2(x) 
=> 5x - 1 + 3x + 4
=> 8x +3
```

My question is, how can this be done in python? If my dataset is `X`, I'm using statsmodels like this:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std
import numpy as np

mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, X)
res_wls = mod_wls.fit()
print res_wls.params
```

And that gives me the coefficients for the regression function that fits the data `X`.
To add the functions, I can easily grab the coefficients for each, and sum them up to get the coefficients for a new regression function such as G(x). But now that I've got my own coefficients, how can I convert them into a regression function and use them to predict a new data? Because as far as I know, models have to be "fitted" to data before they can be used for prediction.

Or is there any way to directly add regression functions? I'm going to be adding functions iteratively in my algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prediction generated by this model should be exactly

```
np.dot(X_test, res_wls.params)
```

Thus, if you want to sum several models, e.g.

```
summed_params = np.array([res_wls.params for res_wls in all_my_res_wls]).sum(axis=0)
```

your prediction should be

```
np.dot(X_test, summed_params)
```

In this case there would be no need to use the built-in functions of the estimator.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the intercept?

Comment: very good point - I am slightly biased towards blindly assuming the data is centered

Comment: I am having difficulties finding a variable in a fitted `sm.WLS` object that would encode an intercept. The docs don't seem to mention it either. Am I missing something (I am not a statsmodels expert)? Otherwise I guess the only way to obtain an intercept is to explicitly add a column of `ones` to `X`

Comment: `help(sm.WLS)` says "An interecept [sic] is not included by default and should be added by the user". Never mind!

Comment: So how would I use (and determine) the intercept to include?

Comment: replace the line `mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, X)` with `mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, np.hstack([np.ones(len(X), 1), X]))`. The intercept will the appear as the first entry in `params`

Comment: I just want to confirm - because I forgot to mention in the question - the shape of dataset `X` is `[n_samples, n_features]`. That doesn't create any problems, right?

Comment: This is the standard shape for many algorithms/packages, and is the order I assumed (I am adding a feature, i.e. a column, which is the vector of `ones`)

Comment: Thanks so much for the above, I meant to check it as a correct answer after trying it out, but I'm stuck on the intermediate step before getting to this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345715/python-error-len-of-unsized-object-while-using-statsmodels-with-one-row-of-da any ideas?

Comment: Okay it's working! However, using the modified line to include the intercept is giving this error:     `mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, np.hstack([np.ones(len(X), 1), X]), weights) 
...  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 148, in ones....    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)... TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: @eickenberg The prediction you mentioned here (`np.dot(X_test, summed_params)`) worked perfectly. But how would the same thing be done for a 2D `endog` array? In the above example when we fitted the data,(`mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, X)`) , `y` was a 1D array. What if it had 2 columns? How would we then use `np.dot()`? To clarify, I've asked it as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369859/how-to-get-the-prediction-of-test-from-2d-parameters-of-wls-regression-in-statsm